# JW Player fails with error with wma files: Task Queue failed at step 5

Tags: php, ffmpeg, jwplayer, wma

I have a JW Player which plays MP3 files but with WMA files it gives the error:

```
Task Queue failed at step 5: Playlist could not be loaded: Playlist file did not contain a valid playlist
```

I thought of two reasons:

1. There is no support for WMA but please confirm me this.
2. Somewhere I need to setup the type of file I am using in this player.

If WMA not supported in JW Player how can I play WMA and MP3 files in my website?

Is `ffmpeg` needed to convert WMA to MP3 while uploading?

Answer (score 1):

## JW Player does not support WMA

According to the [Media Format Reference](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635) JW Player 8+ officially supports:

- 2 video file types: MP4 and WebM.
- 3 audio file types: AAC, MP3 and Vorbis.
- 2 streaming protocols: HLS and DASH.
- RSS feeds, using enclosures or the Media or JWPlayer extension.
- JSON feeds

Also see the *Supported Audio Files* section in the link above.

## Re-encode WMA to a supported audio format

You can use `ffmpeg` to encode to one of the supported formats:

### AAC

```
ffmpeg -i input.wma -movflags +faststart output.m4a
```

For more encoding options see [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).

### MP3

```
ffmpeg -i input.wma output.mp3
```

For more encoding options see [FFmpeg Wiki: MP3](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

### Vorbis

```
ffmpeg -i input.wma -c:a libvorbis output.oga
```

For more encoding options see [FFmpeg Wiki: Vorbis](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide).

Comment: thanks for your reply,  to use this ffmpeg how can  i install in cpanel?

Comment: @Sabeena I don't know anything about cpanel.